# Water tank problem (right ODE, wrong solution)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I know there is plethora of this kind of question, but I am stuck with the resolution of a water tank problem.

The question is as follows:
"*A very large tank initially contains 100L of pure water. Starting at time t=0 a solution with a salt concentration of 0.8kg/L is added at a rate of 6L/min. The solution is kept thoroughly mixed and is drained from the tank at a rate of 4L/min.*"

The corresponding ODE is:
$$y'(t) = 4.8- \frac{4y}{(100+2t)}$$

And by using integrating factor $(100 + 2t)^2$ I get:
$$y(t) = 1.6(100+2t) + \frac{C}{(100+2t)^2}$$

And by setting $y(0) = 0$ (the water is supposed to be clean) I get $C = -160 \cdot 100^2$

Yet when I try to solve $y(30) = 1.6\cdot160 - \frac{ -160 \cdot 100^2}{160^2} = 193.5$ I get wrong answer.

What is the obvious thing I am missing here? Am I wrong to assume y(0) = 0?
Thank you!

Comment: What is the final question? You've only included the setup, and I expect the issue is going to be with the units in the final question.

Comment: The units should be kgs of salt. My final question is why do I get the wrong answer for y(30). But I think I figured out why (just after posting unfortunately), I forgot the inner derivative while integrating LHS (4.8*(100+2t)^2) when calculating y(t).

Comment: Ah yeah I see what you mean

Comment: Thank you for looking this way and your time, if you write a little blurb or sentence about not forgetting the inner derivative I will accept your answer :)

Comment: Yes it is, I integrated wrong. If you post an answer I will accept it, since @StephenDonovan declined :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct integral for y(t), as posted in the comments :
$$y(t)=0.8(100+2t)+\frac{C}{(100+2t)^2}$$
Since there is a factor 2 in front of t, we need also to divide with the inner derivative. This brings the factor 1.6 to 0.8.